# Where do you keep XHR calls in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I'm wondering where to keep all these XHR calls in Ember.js application for non *ember-data* calls.

When using ember-data with REST adapter things are easy and clear, but what if:

- **Need to use WebSocket to make connection**
- **Need to make some call to retrieve data from API but not related to any model in the app**

Write WebSocket/XHR code in controller or create some adapter?

Any suggestion appreciated how to lay out Ember.js app.

Comment: What do you mean keep the XHR calls? Your models don't need to derive from DS.Model. You can have models that extend Ember.Object and handle fetching your data however you want. For example, if you have a find() function on your class that returns an empty instance that is later populated by the callback from an ajax call with the success handler executed with the new instance as its context, then this handler can set the properties in a KVO-compliant way causing any desired downstream bindings to update or observers to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Data access should occur in the model layer, either as class and instance methods of the models themselves, or in data access objects that the models collaborate with.